# Terraform If-Else Logic inside resource

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to write terraform code where I need to run some sql queries (using local-exec) depending on the value of a variable (say **execute_sql**).

So, the logic is as follows:

```
resource "null_resource" "execute_sh" {
If var.execute_sql == 1 then 
provisioner "local-exec" {
     command = templatefile("${path.module}/xyz.sh.tpl", {
      .........
      .....
}}}
else do nothing.
```

Basically execute the sh file only if the value of the variable execute_sql = 1.

Can someone suggest on how to get this logic working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `count`:

```
resource "null_resource" "execute_sh" {

  count = var.execute_sql == 1 ? 1 : 0 

  provisioner "local-exec" {
     command = templatefile("${path.module}/xyz.sh.tpl", {
      .........
      .....
}
```

Comment: On top of what Marcin says, which is 100% correct, if what you intend is to create the resource but optionally launch the `provisioner "local_exec"` (which makes no sense, btw), you would instead move the ternary from the count to the command. So instead it would look like this:
`command = var.execute_sql == 1 ? "echo does nothing" : "launch the sql"`